# PHP File That Responds To HTTP Post Request

Tags: php, http, post, https

How would I create a .php file, that when sent a POST request to it (That includes data) would respond?
For example, I send a POST request to http://example.com/example.php with {username: "test"} and it responds with "test".

Comment: That's php web programming 101.  Spend a few hours studying LAMP principles and come back with some code if you can't get it working.  http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you mean to respond to any post request as long it is post
You can try the
 If(   strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'post'){echo "test";}

Or 
You use

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data);
echo $data['username'];
```

Or

```
 echo $_POST['username'];
```

All these depending on how the request is sent, but you can still clarify more.

Comment: Huh, I'm getting an empty response when I send the request.

Comment: Here is the thing your question isn't so clear, let me ask so it is easier to answer your question, how are you sending the request? via form? ajax? or another server is sending to you

Comment: Ok, it's working, I'm just gonna make a seperate parser for it. Thanks!